# Capturing screenshots in Firefox in a loop

Tags: javascript, firefox, screenshot

Firefox's [:screenshot](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/web_console/helpers/index.html) helper function is perfect for my needs (I need the `--dpr` parameter in particular), so I'd like to put it in a loop (e.g. take a screenshot, wait 1 second, take another, etc), to avoid having to manually refocus the Web Console, re-enter the command, return to the webpage, etc.

However, I'm unable to integrate it into a Javascript loop in the Web Console:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    :screenshot --fullpage --dpr 2
}
```

This results in a syntax error (expected, since `:screenshot` is not Javascript):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got ':'
```

​How can I call `:screenshot` in a loop?